# Creating data frame with repeat rows

Tags: r, iteration, repeat

I want to create a data frame with rows that repeat.

Here is my original dataset:

```
> mtcars_columns_a
  variables_interest data_set data_set_and_variables_interest      mean
1                mpg   mtcars                      mtcars$mpg  20.09062
2               disp   mtcars                     mtcars$disp 230.72188
3                 hp   mtcars                       mtcars$hp 146.68750
```

Here is my desire dataset

```
> mtcars_columns_b
  variables_interest data_set data_set_and_variables_interest      mean
1                mpg   mtcars                      mtcars$mpg  20.09062
2                mpg   mtcars                      mtcars$mpg  20.09062
3               disp   mtcars                     mtcars$disp 230.72188
4               disp   mtcars                     mtcars$disp 230.72188
5                 hp   mtcars                       mtcars$hp 146.68750
6                 hp   mtcars                       mtcars$hp 146.68750
```

I know how to do this the long way manually, but this is time consuming and rigid. Is there a quicker way to do this that is more automated and flexible?

---

---

Here is the code I used to create the dataset:

```
# mtcars data

## displays data
mtcars

## 3 row data set

### lists columns of interest
# ---- NOTE: REQUIRES MANUAL INPUT
# ---- NOTE: lists variables of interest
mtcars_columns_a <- 
  data.frame(
    c(
      "mpg",
      "disp",
      "hp"
    )
  )
# ---- NOTE: REQUIRES MANUAL INPUT
# ---- NOTE: adds colnames
names(mtcars_columns_a)[names(mtcars_columns_a) == 'c..mpg....disp....hp..'] <- 'variables_interest'

### adds data set info
mtcars_columns_a$data_set <- 
  c("mtcars")

### creates data_set_and_variables_interest column
mtcars_columns_a$data_set_and_variables_interest <- 
  paste(mtcars_columns_a$data_set,mtcars_columns_a$variables_interest,sep = "$")

### creates mean column
mtcars_columns_a$mean <-
  c(
    mean(mtcars$mpg),
    mean(mtcars$disp),
    mean(mtcars$hp)
  )

## 6 row data set., the long way

### lists columns of interest
# ---- NOTE: REQUIRES MANUAL INPUT
# ---- NOTE: lists variables of interest
mtcars_columns_b <- 
  data.frame(
    c(
      "mpg",
      "mpg",
      "disp",
      "disp",
      "hp",
      "hp"
    )
  )
# ---- NOTE: REQUIRES MANUAL INPUT
# ---- NOTE: adds colnames
names(mtcars_columns_b)[names(mtcars_columns_b) == 'c..mpg....mpg....disp....disp....hp....hp..'] <- 'variables_interest'

### adds data set info
mtcars_columns_b$data_set <- 
  c("mtcars")

### creates data_set_and_variables_interest column
mtcars_columns_b$data_set_and_variables_interest <- 
  paste(mtcars_columns_b$data_set,mtcars_columns_b$variables_interest,sep = "$")

### creates mean column
mtcars_columns_b$mean <-
  c(
    mean(mtcars$mpg),
    mean(mtcars$mpg),
    mean(mtcars$disp),
    mean(mtcars$disp),
    mean(mtcars$hp),
    mean(mtcars$hp)
  )
```

Comment: From your desired output it seems you can just do rbind(mtcars_columns_a, mtcars_columns_a)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `rep` like below

```
mtcars_columns_a[rep(seq(nrow(mtcars_columns_a)), each = 2),]
```

Answer (score 3):

Another option is `uncount`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
mtcars_columns_a %>%
   uncount(2)
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on your expected output is this the sort of thing you were after?

The selection of required variables is made with the `select` function and the mean calculated using the `summarise` function following  `group_by` variables.

The duplication of data and adding of additional variables (not really sure if these are necessary) is carried out using mutate.

You can edit variable names using the `dplyr::rename` function.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)


df <- 
  mtcars %>% 
  select(mpg, disp, hp) %>% 
  pivot_longer(everything()) %>% 
  group_by(name) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(value))

df1 <- 
  bind_rows(df, df) %>% 
  arrange(name) %>% 
  mutate(dataset = "mtcars",
         variable = paste(dataset, name, sep = "$"))

df1
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>   name   mean dataset variable   
#>   <chr> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>      
#> 1 disp  231.  mtcars  mtcars$disp
#> 2 disp  231.  mtcars  mtcars$disp
#> 3 hp    147.  mtcars  mtcars$hp  
#> 4 hp    147.  mtcars  mtcars$hp  
#> 5 mpg    20.1 mtcars  mtcars$mpg 
#> 6 mpg    20.1 mtcars  mtcars$mpg
```

<sup>Created on 2021-04-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v1.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The order of records in a `data.frame` object is usually not meaningful, so you could just do:

```
rbind(mtcars_columns_a, mtcars_columns_a)
```

If you need it to be in the order you showed, this is also simple:

```
mtcars_columns_b <- rbind(mtcars_columns_a, mtcars_columns_a)
mtcars_columns_b[order(mtcars_columns_b, mtcars_columns_b$name),]
```